# How can I format a Sequelize filter as valid JSON

Tags: json, node.js, api, sequelize.js

I am setting up an API. The server receives from the client a filter in the form of JSON to be used by sequelize when querying a MySQL database.

I have been testing with postman.

The following json, can be sent to the server, but sequelize does not like `"[Op.or]"` because it should be `[Op.or]`  without the quotes.

However if I don't add the quotes, then it is not valid JSON and I can not post the data.

```
//Sequelize does not like this because of the quotes around "[Op.or]"
{
    "filters": {"week": 201740, "project": 8, "itemgroup": {"[Op.or]": ["group1", "group2"]}}
}

//This is can not be sent as a JSON body in an API request because there are
//no quotes around [Op.or]
{
    "filters": {"week": 201740, "project": 8, "itemgroup": {[Op.or]: ["group1", "group2"]}}
}
```

Here is my script file where the sequelize call is made.The JSON filter is passed in via the filters variable in the function header.

```
module.exports = {
    getAOLDataCount:  function (res, filters) {
        let result = '';
        wd = new WeeklyData(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        wd.count({where: filters}).then(function (aolCount) {
            res.send('the value ' + aolCount);
        });
        return result;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your client (presumably) would not have Sequelize installed and cannot pass a Sequelize operator via JSON, so what you are trying to do is not exactly possible. You would probably to get the client to send string (e.g. `or`, `and` and then you would have to map those string to Sequelize operators) [1].

```
"filters": {"week": 201740, "project": 8, "itemgroup": {"or": ["group1", "group2"]}}
```

Then in your server code you would need to maintain a map of strings to Sequelize operators:

```
const operatorsMap = {
  or: [Op.or],
  and: [Op.and],
  etc
}
```

And for each request, you then to loop over all keys and replace strings with the Sequelize operators.

```
function isObject(o) {
  return o instanceof Object && o.constructor === Object;
}

function replacer(obj) {
  var newObj = {};
  for (key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];

    if (isObject(value)) {
      newObj[key] = replacer(value);
    } else if (operatorsMap[key]) {
      var op = operatorsMap[key];
      newObj[op] = value;
    } else {
      newObj[key] = value
    }
  }

  return newObj;
}

module.exports = {
    getAOLDataCount:  function (res, filters) {
        let result = '';
        wd = new WeeklyData(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        wd.count({where: replacer(filters)}).then(function (aolCount) {
            res.send('the value ' + aolCount);
        });
        return result;
    }
};
```

FYI, The code above has not been tested.

[1] Without knowing the specifics of your project, I would recommend you reconsider this approach. The client really should not send a JSON object that gets fed directly to the ORM. What about bad SQL injection? What if you upgrade Sequelize and old filters get deprecated? Instead, considering allowing filtering via query paramters and have your API create a filter object based on that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This is an internal application API used on a closed network, so SQL injection is highly unlikely. The main driver for this approach is that the current reporting application written in PHP has got out of hand with different departments wanting to filter data in different ways and trying to keep up with an ever growing list of filters was tiring. With this approach the client can just push it's filter requirements direct to the API.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of mcranston18's answer that runs:

```
const Op = this.Sequelize.Op;
this.operatorsMap = { // Add additional operators as needed.
    $ne: Op.ne,
};
replaceOperators(oldObject) {
    let newObject = {};
    for (let key in oldObject) {
        let value = oldObject[key];

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            newObject[key] = this.replaceOperators(value); // Recurse

        } else if (this.operatorsMap[key]) {
            let op = this.operatorsMap[key];
            newObject[op] = value;

        } else {
            newObject[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return newObject;
}
```

With this code you can do things like:

```
let whereFilter = {"emailAddress":"xxx@xxx.org","id":{"$ne":7}};
let objectFilter = JSON.parse(whereFilter);
let translatedObjectFilter = this.replaceOperators(objectFilter);
let options = {};
options.where = translatedObjectFilter;
await this.table.findAll(options).then(....
```

By getting the ability to translate string operators to work for Sequelize calls, struggling devs can accomplish much more on client side single page applications because there's no need to write a specific server side query with literal objects for every different client query. The server side framework can be generic, rather than application specific.

For example, the SPA I'm building has a server framework of a mere 5 js files. The client has 28 js files and growing. This uses Sequelize 4.37.10.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out from the sequelize slack group that the old operator method is still in the codebase. I don't know how long it will stay, but since it is the only way of sending via json, it may well stay.

So the way it works is that rather than using [Op.or] you can use $or.

Example:

```
"filters": {"week": 201740, "project": 8, "itemgroup": {"$or": ["group1", "group2"]}}
```

Comment: This will indeed work. Keep in mind string based operators were deprecated for security reasons (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators-security)